# Broadcom BCM4313 802.11bgn can connect to WIFI but not to internet

Tags: wireless, internet, broadcom, thinkpad

I was running Windows 8.1 and very recently switched to UBUNTU. I am very new here but have read an enormous amount of posts pertaining to this problem.

I have a ThinkPad E530. I can route the Wifi through my phone and connect to the internet. My computer connects to the wifi but is not able to connect to the Internet through the WIFI.

At some point using Windows, I had to change wifi power settings and I think it is a similar problem here. I just have no idea how to fix it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth1
   version: 01
   serial: 2c:d0:5a:fc:d0:08
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) ip=192.168.2.103 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:17 memory:e4100000-e4103fff
```

iwconfig

```
wwan0     no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Our-Wifi-Name"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: 44:94:FC:A1:C4:B1   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

In your terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source bcmwl-modaliases
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that bcmwl-kernel-source, which you already have installed, is incorrect for your device. I suggest:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

It may take a reboot.